# Function getUrl of magento 2 doesn't work correct

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, url

In template I try to get url link but it doesn't work correct. I try to use this code:

```
$block->getUrl('aloha/product/view/id/')
```

But it always return http://abcs.com/aloha/product/view/, Is this a bug?

Comment: What you want here? ulr looks good.

Comment: The result should I expect is abcs.com/aloha/product/view/id/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $block->getUrl('aloha/product/view/id/')

This is the wrong approach. Try following way:

```
$block->getUrl('aloha/product/view', ['id' => 22])
```

**[Update]**

According to your comment you need url using id. GetUrl will return **route/contoller/actionclass** and ignore remaining string. In your case, try following way:

```
$block->getUrl('aloha/product/view').'/id'
```

Comment: The issue is I don't have id when I use this function(I will add id in Jquery). Do you know why Magento remove id in last?

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: It work. Thank you!